# Why do I still have item outlines?

Tags: risk-of-rain

In Risk of Rain, the [Soldier's Syringe](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Soldier%27s_Syringe) and [Laser Turbine](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Laser_Turbine) still appear only in outline in my item log even though I've collected them both multiple times.

Now, I did cheat both of these in using the [Command Artifact](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Command) before I actually unlocked them. I thought that I simply needed to collect them in at least one game after unlocking them to have these filled in in the item log, but I've collected both in new games after this and they still appear as shadows.

**What, if anything, can I do to have these filled in and click-able in my item log?**

[image]

Comment: In order to unlock them, you have to complete corresponding achievement. You can still use them via the Command Artifact but it doesn't fully count until you get the achievement.

Comment: @slow_excellence I have unlocked them, hence the outline. If they were locked, they would appear as a lock icon (like others in my picture). They are locked until you complete the achievement and then outlined until you collect them in game.

Comment: hmm, maybe you have to collect it in normal mode? I'm at a loss since a good chunk of my artifacts are like that and I thought it was because I  hadn't finished the achievement haha

Comment: I second @slow_excellence's question - what difficulty were you playing when you found these items in-game without using the Command artifact? Try finding the item in game normally on Rainstorm (normal) or Monsoon difficulty and see if the item appears.

Comment: @culix Thanks for the thought. I misunderstood slow_excellence thinking that "normal mode" meant "without the command artifact". However, I have been playing entirely on Rainstorm (normal) difficulty, when collecting the items before and after unlocking them.

Comment: At very worst, if you know you've legitimately unlocked the item descriptions but aren't able to figure out why this isn't working, you could always just edit your save file and add them. There have been similar bugs in past updates, such as the Loader being unable to unlock an achievement for killing an Overloaded Magma Worm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the Soldier's Syringe, [this is a known bug](http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Soldier%27s_Syringe#Bugs).

> When you collect the soldier's syringe, it doesn't unlock in your item log. There is no official fix, but as a temporary fix you can open the save file and add the soldier's syringe to the save values there (item20=1).

For the Laser Turbine, I can't find anything on the wiki, [but it has also been reported as a bug](http://community.playstarbound.com/index.php?threads/bug-reports-for-risk-of-rain-1-2-3.86193/page-2#post-2301514) together with the Ancient Scepter.